# Job не содержит определения для lol

Tags: c#

есть метод:

```
public class Job
{
    public string name, firm, city;
    public int cost;
    static void lol()
    {
        int i = 0;
    }
}
```

и у меня не получается обратиться к статическому полю, выдает ошибку "Job не содержит определения для lol"

```
Job.lol();
```

с чем это может быть связано?(

Comment: `public static void lol(...`

Comment: ну блин, как я сам не понял. Спасибо) как-то переработал)

Answer (score 3):

ошибка в том, что модификатор доступа не определил "public static void lol(...". Спасибо Igor за подсказку)

Comment: На здоровье. Успехов в программировании!